# Count number of rows with a specific MONTH in the date of a specific cell and a boolean condition in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

Let's say I have a number of dates and whether they occupy full or half a day...

```
   DATE  |         WHAT        | HALF?
...
2021-4-1 | Something Something | false
2021-4-2 | Something Something | false
2021-4-5 | Something Something | false
2021-4-19| Something Something | true
2021-5-13| Something Something | false
2021-5-24| Something Something | false
2021-9-13| Something Something | true
...
```

I now want for each month the amount of half-days occupied in that list.
(e.g. for `April` that should be `1` in the examples above, for `May` that should be `0`)

I.e. in pseudocode, I'm looking for something like

```
=COUNTIF(A8:A, `MOTH of row = MONTH(E2)` AND `half of row = true`)
```

where `E2`, in this case, is e.g. `January` stored as a date

and `A8:A` contains the dates of the above table (i.e. `B8:B` contains the `WHAT` and `C8:C` contains the `HALF?`)

Comment: please choose either excel or google.  One is on topic here and the other is not.

Comment: @ScottCraner I was expecting a solution for either to work in the other, but preference clearly for google sheets, in that case.

Comment: Then this question belongs on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: BTW, you need to book end the dates, count the dates between the 1st and last day of the month.

Comment: And use COUNTIFS not COUNTIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A8:A` range references do not work in Excel.

Use COUNTIFS not COUNTIF and bookend the dates:

```
=COUNTIFS(A8:A1040000,">="&EOMONTH(E2,-1)+1,A8:A1040000,"<"&EOMONTH(E2,0)+1,C8:C1040000,FALSE)
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you.